# rails import csv data from dynamic url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm completely newbie with RoR. What I'm trying to do is to import data from an asp url:
I've a ticket that passed to this url it returns with some informations like time_created, time_updated, owner, notes. I've tried putting this code in my view:

```
<% file = open("http://xxx.xxx.xxx/utility/ticket_dettagli.asp?TT="+@Ticket.ticket) %>

<%= CSV.new(file, col_sep: ',').readlines do |row| %>
   <%= Ticket.create! row.to_hash %>
<% end %>
```

without success...any suggestion?

Comment: Where is your code failing?

Comment: It returns with: `undefined method 'ticket' for #<Class:0x00000004c455c8>`

Comment: How is @Ticket defined?  I think that is your fundamental problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do this in view? I think, there should be rake task for import tickets form csv or class method in your model ...

See: http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel

`@Ticket` - is this a variable? How you declare it?

Comment: I've followed the railcast, but I don't know how to associate the argument "Ticket" with the url. Ticket is the name of the class

Comment: if you have method in Ticket class named ticket, which return string you can pass it by `url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/utility/ticket_dettagli.asp?TT=#{Ticket.ticket}"`

Comment: Sorry but could you write me an example? I've to pass to a form the ticket number, which download from the url a csv file. And then I have to print the output.